# Sorting List of objects in android

Tags: java, android, list, sorting

Suppose I have the following object class:

```
public class Country {
    private int ID;
    private String name;
    private Double distance;
}
```

and I have a list of this object which contain many objects:

```
List<Country> myList;
```

how i can sort the list based on the `Double distance` e.g to put objects with less distance first? Is there a ready function to do this?

Or i want to store 3 countries of minimum distances in another list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `Collection.sort` and pass your own implementation of `Comparator`

## Example:

```
List<Country> items = new ArrayList<Country>();
        
.....
Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<Country>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Country o1, Country o2) {
        return Double.compare(o1.getDistance(), o2.getDistance());
    }

});
```

Comment: Comparator doesn't need to be anonymous. Maybe it is better to reword it as "your own" or something similar to avoid possible misunderstandings.

Comment: thanks dear, regards. @ΦXoce웃Пepeúpa

Comment: Got it... I will rephrase that

Comment: @MSMC you are welcome